# AOSP difference between multi-window and multi-display

Tags: android-source

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between multi-window and and multi-display in the AOSP environment.

Answer (score 3):

**multi-window**

> devices can display multiple apps simultaneously using multi-window. Android supports three multi-window configurations:
>
> - **Split-screen** is the default multi-window implementation, which provides two activity panes where users can place apps.
> - **Freeform** allows users to dynamically resize the activity panes and have more than two apps visible on their screen.
> - **Picture-in-picture (PIP)** allows Android devices to play video content in a small window while the user interacts with other apps.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi-window

---

**multi-display**

Devices can now have multiple physical displays and inputs. Example: Two people can use the same Android device via two different displays at the same time. This is a new feature to Android Q and comes with a ton of limitations so far.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi_display